# Whats meaning subscripting self?

Tags: ios, swift

I've encountered some strange line of code in Eureka project [here](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/blob/master/Source/Core.swift)

```
public subscript(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> BaseRow {
    return self[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
}
```

And it confused me. How it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the other answers define what subscripting in general is, but from the title of your post, I'm assuming that you are asking what the line

```
return self[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
```

does.

It's quite simple really, it's applying a subscript to `self` and then another subscript to the result. This function

```
public subscript(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> BaseRow {
    return self[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
}
```

defines a subscript on an `NSIndexSet` in terms of other already defined subscripts. The `section` property of an `NSIndexSet` is an int and you'll see that the Form class defines a subscript on `Int` in this extension:

```
extension Form : MutableCollectionType {

    // MARK: MutableCollectionType

    public var startIndex: Int { return 0 }
    public var endIndex: Int { return kvoWrapper.sections.count }
    public subscript (position: Int) -> Section {
        get { return kvoWrapper.sections[position] as! Section }
        set { kvoWrapper.sections[position] = newValue }
    }
}
```

So `self[indexPath.section]` returns a `Section` object which is then subscripted by another int (`indexPath.row`) to return a `BaseRow` (see further down to see the `Int` subscript on `Section`).

Answer (score 2):

Adding this method to a class or struct

```
public subscript (index: Int) -> Element {
    // ...
}
```

does allow you to use subscripting with your own class.

Example

```
public class Sentence {

    private let words: [String]

    init(sentence:String) {
        self.words = sentence.characters.split(" ").map(String.init)
    }

    public subscript (index: Int) -> String {
        return words[index]
    }
}

let sentence = Sentence(sentence: "Hello world")
sentence[0] // "Hello"
//       ^ <-- this will call the subscript method
```

Answer (score 2):

By the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Subscripts.html)

> **Subscripts**
>
> Classes, structures, and enumerations can define subscripts, which are >shortcuts for accessing the member elements of a collection, list,
> or sequence. You use subscripts to set and retrieve values by index
> without needing separate methods for setting and retrieval. For
> example, you access elements in an Array instance as someArray[index]
> and elements in a Dictionary instance as someDictionary[key].
>
> You can define multiple subscripts for a single type, and the appropriate >subscript overload to use is selected based on the type of
> index value you pass to the subscript. Subscripts are not limited to a
> single dimension, and you can define subscripts with multiple input
> parameters to suit your custom type’s needs.

```
•   struct TimesTable {
         let multiplier: Int
         subscript(index: Int) -> Int {
             return multiplier * index
         }
    }

let threeTimesTable = TimesTable(multiplier: 3)

println("six times three is \(threeTimesTable[6])")

// prints "six times three is 18"
```